# How to catch all urls with a single route file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to define a route in next.js to catch this urls:

```
https://mytestsite.com/mypath/document (this is to upload a document)
https://mytestsite.com/mypath/document/123 (this is to edit document id 123)
```

to do this I need two files:

```
/mypath/document/index.tsx
/mypath/document/[...all].tsx
```

is it possible to have a single file to catch all the above urls?

Comment: Use double brackets: `[[...all]].tsx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Optional catch all routes

Catch all routes can be made optional by including the parameter in double brackets ([[...slug]]).

For example, pages/post/[[...slug]].js will match /post, /post/a, /post/a/b, and so on.