# Route index page to dynamic page in Next.js

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I'm working on a Next.js project with this structure:

- pages

  - [site]

    - [id].js
    - index.js

But I wan't to combine both.js since they have the same code. But if I remove the index.js, the request to index are not routed to the [id].js page.

The is any way to combine them?

Comment: You can use an [optional catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes). See [How to catch all urls with a single route file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869718/how-to-catch-all-urls-with-a-single-route-file)

Comment: Thanks! It worked halfway, I cant return notFound:true in the static props, it still handling the routes in a differente way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the [id].js page, the route should match `/[site]/[id]`
I would recommend removing the [id].js instead and using passing the `id` as a query. Then retrieve the `id`.
Checkout [this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/heuristic-silence-nqkfue?file=%2Fpages%2F%5Bsite%5D%2Findex.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A14%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A11%2C%22startColumn%22%3A3%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A9%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522claoe1c7v005l286dww5nqobo%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522%252Fpages%252F%255Bsite%255D%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522%252Fpages%252Findex.tsx%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522claodys52000n286d1u52x456%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fsite%253Fid%253Dleangchhean%2522%257D%255D%257D) codesanbox